# Get items that have more than 1 row with the same effective date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I'm looking to run SQL in SQL Server 2014 that will get me items (`INV_ITEM_ID`) that have more than 1 row in the table, **and** have the same Effective date (`EFFDT`) as shown in the below example.

```
SETID   INV_ITEM_ID VENDOR_SETID    VENDOR_ID   UNIT_OF_MEASURE   EFFDT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SHARE   1           SHARE           ERSUT       BX                2018-07-16 00:00:00.000
SHARE   1           SHARE           ERSUT       BX                2018-09-01 00:00:00.000
SHARE   10          SHARE           ERSUT       RL                1901-01-01 00:00:00.000
SHARE   100         SHARE           JJHS        CS                1901-01-01 00:00:00.000
SHARE   100         SHARE           PSMED       CS                1901-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Item 100 from the above output would be a good example of an item that occurs more than once AND has the same EFFDT (1901-01-01) on both rows.

This is the SQL I have tried, however it is not giving me the expected output:

```
SELECT 
    SETID, INV_ITEM_ID, VENDOR_SETID, VENDOR_ID, UNIT_OF_MEASURE, EFFDT
FROM 
    PS_ITM_VNDR_UOM_PR A
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PS_ITM_VNDR_UOM_PR B
            WHERE B.INV_ITEM_ID = A.INV_ITEM_ID AND B.EFFDT = A.EFFDT)
GROUP BY 
    SETID, INV_ITEM_ID, VENDOR_SETID, VENDOR_ID, UNIT_OF_MEASURE, EFFDT
HAVING 
    COUNT(INV_ITEM_ID) > 1 AND COUNT(EFFDT) > 1
ORDER BY 
    INV_ITEM_ID
```

Comment: What if INV_ITEM_ID = 1 had an extra row equals to the first row? Would it meet the criteria or not? It will have three rows (two with the same date).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM 
    TABLENAME a
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT
    COUNT(1) cnt
    ,inv_item_id
    ,effdt
FROM
    TABLENAME b
WHERE b.inv_item_id = a.inv_item_id
GROUP BY inv_item_id,effdt
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query should get what you want:

```
with x as (
select inv_item_id, effdt
  from ps_itm_vndr_uom_pr
  group by inv_item_id, effdt
  having count(*) > 1 
)
select inv_item_id
  from x
  group by inv_item_id
  having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, So this returns the rows that will have a corresponding row with the same INV_ITEM_ID and EFFDT. Is it possible to display the duplicates as well so that for example I see in my results Item 100 twice?

Answer (score 0):

You want to select all rows for which the row count of `INV_ITEM_ID` and `EFFDT` > 1. This is easily solved with `COUNT OVER`:

```
select setid, inv_item_id, vendor_setid, vendor_id, unit_of_measure, effdt
from
(
  select *, count(*) over (partition by inv_item_id, effdt) as cnt
  from ps_itm_vndr_uom_pr
) t
where cnt > 1
order by inv_item_id, effdt;
```